# Will Perl's $@ ever be undefined after an eval?

Tags: perl, eval

I'm working on the ["Error Handling and Reporting"](http://www.masteringperl.org/2013/07/new-to-error-handling/) chapter of [Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org). In [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)'s entry for `$@`, it says:

> The Perl syntax error message from the last eval() operator. If $@ is the null string, the last eval() parsed and executed correctly (although the operations you invoked may have failed in the normal fashion).

Now I'm wondering when an [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) might not execute correctly, leaving `$@` with an undefined value. Are there any such cases?

Comment: This returns a null string: `perl -MData::Dumper -e'$@=123; eval q{$@=456}; print(Dumper($@));'` But the description is not correct. `$@` is set to the argument of `die` if it is executed. Otherwise, it's a null string.

Comment: I don't care about the null string case. That's defined behavior. I'm asking about the converse case.

Comment: `$@` is also the null string if no eval has been executed: `perl5.14.2 -E 'say q(\$@ is the empty string) if $@ eq q()'`

Comment: Reading the answers/comments, I would suggest putting the exact definition of "execute correctly" into the question. Everyone's got their own idea.

Comment: I don't know what that definition is, and that definition is the crux of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody reads the question and still wonders (like I did) if `$@` can be undefined after the `eval`, I believe the answer is no.  (I had also read about it being "null" in [old 5.8.3 docs for $@](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.3/variables/$EVAL_ERROR), and I was confused because "null" isn't a term often used in Perl.)

I don't have knowledge of the Perl internals to confirm this, but it looks like the docs were eventually fixed in 2015 with [this commit](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/2e6ba1150254777d642a3d2dad711591e2b49479), which came about due to [this issue](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/14572).  [perlvar's entry](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$@) now says "empty string" instead of "null":

> The Perl error from the last "eval" operator, i.e. the last exception that was caught. For "eval BLOCK", this is either a runtime error message or the string or reference "die" was called with. The "eval STRING" form also catches syntax errors and other compile time exceptions.
>
> If no error occurs, "eval" sets $@ to the empty string.

---

Also, given $@ can be set to the "string or reference die was called with", I thought I would make sure `die undef` didn't do it.  Indeed, doing that is caught and handled by Perl:

```bash
% perl -we 'eval { die undef }; print "EVAL_ERROR: $@"'
Use of uninitialized value in die at -e line 1.
EVAL_ERROR: Died at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

The [BACKGROUND section of the Try::Tiny docs](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny#BACKGROUND) contain some info on how `$@` can be clobbered and why Try::Tiny takes special care to avoid clobberage, and always tests the return value of `eval` rather than testing `$@` for truth. All of them are in there because *someone* ran into them at some point, but I think that the `eval`-in-`DESTROY` scenario is the one most likely to trip someone up. Basically, if `die` causes some object to go out of scope, and that object has a `DESTROY` that calls `eval`, then the value that you `die`d with to begin with is irretrievably lost. Assuming the `eval` in the `DESTROY` *doesn't* throw an error, `$@` will be `""` following the outer `eval`.

Comment: It's not talking about clobbering. It could just as easy be clobbered by a different value.

Comment: And note that `$@` has been protected from such clobbering for the last version or two.

Comment: I don't care about it being clobbered and I'm not at all asking about situations where you get a different value than you expect. I know about those things.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it (but sit down before you read it. ;))

```
$@ = 123;
eval q{
  $@ = 456;
  print ">>>$@<<<\n";
  goto SKIP;
};

SKIP:
print ">>>$@<<<\n";
```

Comment: @shawnhcorey considered harmful :-P

Comment: Perl where the easy things are easy, the difficult are possible, but the impossible takes some thought. ;)

Comment: One way to do what? I don't see an undef value in eval in this one. That's interesting, but it's not even close to an answer to my question.

Comment: @briandfoy shawnhcorey's answer demonstrates that we can give `$@` *any* value via exiting an `eval` with `goto`. E.g. `perl -E'eval{$@=undef; goto SAY}; SAY: defined $@ or say "undef"'`.

Comment: @amon Nonetheless, such an eval() executes correctly. For some defintion of the word...

Comment: According to Turning, any program that halts is an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Who said anything about setting `$@` to undef?

"The last eval() parsed and executed correctly" doesn't make any sense: `eval` isn't parsed at runtime. Surely, it means "the last eval() whose expression was parsed and executed correctly". In other words, "the last eval() whose expression compiled and didn't throw any exceptions when executed".

```
>perl -MData::Dumper -e"$@=123; eval ''; print(Dumper($@));"
$VAR1 = '';

>perl -MData::Dumper -e"$@=123; eval '~~~'; print(Dumper($@));"
$VAR1 = 'syntax error at (eval 1) line 2, at EOF
';

>perl -MData::Dumper -e"$@=123; eval 'die q{x}'; print(Dumper($@));"
$VAR1 = 'x at (eval 1) line 1.
';
```

Comment: I said something about $@ being undef. Your examples are all evaluating correctly, I think, and catching errors, like they should. My question is if there will ever be a situation where it doesn't execute correctly. If not, as you suggest, I think the docs need an update so it doesn't imply some other situation that might exist (i.e. where it isn't parsed and executed correctly).

Comment: There is a situation where it isn't parsed and executed correctly. In that situation, `$@` contains the error message. I gave an example of it not parsed correctly, and and example of it not executed correctly. As I've explained, "it" can only refer to `eval`'s operand.

Comment: I re-entered my comment since I wanted to edit it, so your first one is actually a reply. Which one is not executed correctly? If any of them, I would have guessed the second one, but I don't think that's how I'd describe that.

Comment: 2nd fails to parse/compile. 3rd fails to execute. I already said how I'd describe it. ("the last eval() whose expression compiled and didn't throw any exceptions when executed")

Comment: Not throwing exceptions isn't the same as failing to execute. It looks to me like #3 executes normally, doing exactly what die is supposed to do and what eval is supposed to do. The die actually runs.

Comment: Throwing an exception is failing to execute. The failure may be intentional, but that's irrelevant. We've already established the wording it poor.